# seq_cst vs release store on x86

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, atomic, stdatomic

Why the following functions:

```cpp
#include <atomic>

void store_release(std::atomic<int>& location, int val) {
    location.store(val, std::memory_order_release);
}

void store_seq_cst(std::atomic<int>& location, int val) {
   location.store(val, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
}
```

are compiled differently on x86-64 ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/G94756)):

```
store_release(std::atomic<int>&, int):
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], esi
        ret
store_seq_cst(std::atomic<int>&, int):
        xchg    esi, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
```

even though the C++ standard states that store operation with `std::memory_order_seq_cst` order performs a release operation on affected memory location? Quote from 29.3 Order and consistency:

> (1.2) memory_order_release,memory_order_acq_rel, and memory_order_seq_cst: a store operation performs a release operation on the affected memory location

- What guarantees a `xchg` instruction has that `mov` does not have?
- Why are these guarantees required for seq_cst order?
- In which cases the visibility of store will be (practically) different for these 2 operations?

Comment: `xchg` has an implicit `lock` prefix so it flushes the store buffer, just like `mov+mfence` which would also work but is usually slower.  The visibility is unaffected; every store is eventually visible, but it affects *when* it will be visible wrt. later loads.